# ¿Cómo comparar un carácter con las posiciones de una cadena en C#?

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer un programa en el que el usuario introduzca una cadena de caracteres y luego los compare con un carácter específico, en este caso la letra a y me devuelva la cantidad de veces que aparece.

Así como que el usuario pueda introducir un carácter y me diga en que posiciones de la cadena está. Estoy intentando usar la función `subString` pero me lanza errores.

Éste es mi código:

```
Console.Write("Escriba la cadena que desea guardar : ");
cad = Console.ReadLine();


for (i=0 ; i<= cad.Length; i++)
{
     comparacion = cad.Substring(i, 1);
     comp = comparacion.CompareTo(auxiliar);
     if (comp != -1)
     {
         aes = aes+1;
     }

} 


Console.WriteLine(cad);
Console.WriteLine(cad.Length);
Console.WriteLine("El número de veces que se repite la letra a es: " + aes);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: No es necesario usar substring. simplemente accede por posición, `if (cad[i] == auxiliar)...`. Por cierto, es importante al preguntar que nos añadas que errores te está lanzando tu código.

Comment: Qué errores concretos te da? Puedes sacar mucha información de ahí. Además de lo que te ha dicho Pikoh, deberías cambiar el límite superior del bucle, `i<cad.Length` o `i<=cad.Length-1` ya que si no te dará error al leer el último carácter (si tienes una cadena con length = 10, la variable i llegará al valor 10, pero al hacer cad[10] estará intentando coger el 11avo valor, el cual no existe)

Comment: Genial chicos muchas gracias!

Comment: En cuanto tengas una solución que funcione, podrías postearla como respuesta. Si no me equivoco, es una buena práctica en StackOverflow

Answer (score 3):

Dado que la clase `String` implementa `IEnumerable<char>`, se puede conseguir lo que buscas de forma muy sencilla usando LINQ:

```
int CuantasVecesAparece(char caracter, string cadena)
{
    return cadena.Count(c => c == caracter);
}
```

O quizá más fácil de entender: `cadena.Where(c => c == caracter).Count()`

Answer (score 1):

No estas muy lejos de lograr lo que buscas, pero te has desviado al intentar usar [`Substring`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) que no aplica a tu problema, ya que esta funcion hace lo siguiente:

> Recupera una subcadena de la instancia. La subcadena comienza en una
>   posición de carácter especificada y tiene una longitud especificada.

y no es lo que estamos buscando, lo que buscamos, es contar elementos iguales, para lo que sólo necesitamos utilizar un [`if`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/if-else) y una variable en la que podamos ir llevando la cuenta de las repeticiones, por ejemplo

```
string cad = Console.ReadLine();
//Almaceno la letra que busco en una variable
char caracter = 'a';
//Creo una variable para contar las apariciones.
int apariciones = 0;
//Itero la cadena ingresada por el usuario.
for (int i = 0; i < cad.Length-1; i++)
{
    //En caso, de que el caracter que buscamos sea igual al string cad en la posición i
    if (caracter == cad[i])
       //Implica que tenemos que agregar una aparición.
       apariciones++;
}
//Muestro el resultado
Console.WriteLine("El caracter {0} aparece {1} veces", caracter, apariciones);
```

Sobre el código anterior, es muy importante aclarar, que en el `for`, comparamos con `cad.Lenght-1` en lugar de `cad.Lenght` debido a que la propiedad [`string.Lenght`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.length?view=netframework-4.7.2) nos devolverá la cantidad de letras que tiene la cadena, y en `C#` (como en casi todos los lenguajes de programación) se utiliza índice 0, por lo que `cad[cad.Lenght]` produciría la excepción `System.IndexOutOfRangeException`.

---

Para agregar a la respuesta, otra posible solución, puede ser usando [`System.Linq`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq?view=netframework-4.7.2), donde podría hacerse de la siguiente manera:

```
string cad = Console.ReadLine();
//Almaceno la letra que busco en una variable
char caracter = 'a';
//Cuento las apariciones del caracter definido enl a cadena cad.
int apariciones = cad.Count(x => x == caracter);
//Muestro el resultado
Console.WriteLine("El caracter {0} aparece {1} veces", caracter, apariciones);
```

Answer (score 0):

Expresiones regulares
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions

```
string pattern = @"\ban+\w*?\b";

string input = "Autumn is a great time for an annual announcement to all antique collectors.";

foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))

Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at position {1}.", match.Value, match.Index);

// The example displays the following output:   
//       'an' found at position 27.
//       'annual' found at position 30.
//       'announcement' found at position 37.
//       'antique' found at position 57.
```

> El patrón de expresión regular se define como se muestra en la tabla
>   siguiente.
>
> \b    Empieza en un límite de palabras.
>
> an+   Coincide con una "a" seguida de uno o más caracteres "n".
>
> \w*?  Coincide con un carácter de palabra cero o más veces, pero el
>   menor número de veces que sea posible.
>
> \b    Finaliza en un límite de palabras.

Comment: Hola Sergio, esto puede servir de guía para resolver el problema (gracias por poner la referencia), pero sería ideal si pudieras adaptar lo que pones al código compartido en la pregunta. Lee [answer] para más información. Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

te dejo un código que puede servirte de ejemplo.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int cant = ContarCaracter("paralelepípedo", 'e');//Llamamos a la función para saber la cantidad de caracteres pasando como parámetro la palabra y carácter a buscar.

        int[] index = Posiciones("paralelepípedo", 'e', cant);//Llamamos a la función para buscar las posiciones del carácter, pasando como parámetro la palabra, el carácter y la cantidad de veces que se encuentra.

        Console.WriteLine("la palabra paralelepípedo contiene {0} e", cant);//Mostramos la cantidad veces que se encuentra el carácter.
        Console.Write("la letra e se encuentra en las posiciones ");//indicamos las posiciones que se encuentra el carácter.

        foreach (var item in index)//recorremos el array
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", item);//escribimos la posición
            if (item != index.Last())//si el item es diferente de el ultimo elemento
                Console.Write(",");//escribe la coma para separar
        }
        Console.Read();
    }

    public static int ContarCaracter(string palabra, char caracter)//Función para contar caracteres
    {
        int cont = 0;//inicializamos una variable integer para contar
        foreach (var item in palabra)//como string es una cadena podemos utilizar foreach para recorrer y rescatar el carácter
        {
            if (item == caracter)//comparamos el carácter
                cont++;//incrementamos el contador
        }
        return cont;//retornamos el contador con la cantidad de caracteres.
    }

    public static int[] Posiciones(string palabra, char caracter, int cant)
    {
        int[] index = new int[cant];//creamos un array indicando la cantidad de caracteres que debe contener.
        int cont = 1;//inicializamos el contador en 1 para saber la posición del caracter
        int pos = 0;//inicializamos la variable en 0 para utilizar como indice en el array

        foreach (var item in palabra)//utilizamos foreach para recorrer la palabra
        {
            if (item == caracter)//si el carácter es igual
            {
                index[pos] = cont;//guardamos la posición
                pos++;//incrementamos el indice para el array
            }
            cont++;//incrementamos la posición del carácter.
        }
        return index;//retornamos el arreglo con las posiciones.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta funcion ToCharArray() con ella creas un arreglo con las letras de la palabra y utilizas un contador para indicar la cantidad de apariciones del caracter

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cad = "";
        string caracter = "";
        Console.Write("Escriba la cadena que desea guardar : ");
        cad = Console.ReadLine();

        // Usas ToCharArray para convertir la cadena en arreglo.
        char[] arreglo = cad.ToCharArray();

        Console.Write("Escriba el caracter que desea buscar en la cadena : ");
        caracter = Console.ReadLine();

        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arreglo[i].ToString() == caracter)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("El número de veces que se repite la letra (" + caracter + ") en (" + cad + ") es: " + count);
        Console.ReadKey();


    }
```